# Configure Drupal to force login for specific hostname (www. vs manage.) or protocol (HTTP vs HTTPS)

Tags: drupal, permissions, authentication

I have a Drupal site that is available at two different hostnames, one of which is only served using SSL.  For example, http:// www.example.com is for viewing content and https:// manage.example.com is used by content contributors.

I would like to configure Drupal to not show content through the https:// manage.example.com address unless the user has permissions (and is authenticated).

Does Drupal have the ability to set permissions so that a user must login when accessing a site through one hostname but not the other?  Or is there a module which can provide this feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .htaccess to restrict it

Comment: I was looking to use Drupal's authentication system to leverage existing account usernames and passwords and so that users would not need to authenticate twice.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [Domain access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module, it has some tools that may be useful for you. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... a suite of modules that provide tools for running a group of affiliated sites from one Drupal installation and a single shared database.